# How can I stabilize breakpoints from segmented() function?

Tags: r, breakpoints

I found breakpoints with the `breakpoints()` function from the `strucchange` package. My explanatory variable is latitude and response variable is beta diversity value.

Then, I used these breakpoints to fit the regression line and plot it with `segmented()` from the `segmented` package. Segmented provides breakpoints estimates that change when I run the function again. However, breakpoints from breakpoints function do not change. I guess, breakpoints change with bigger set of data, as mine. I need to report these breakpoints.

How can I stabilize breakpoints from the `segmented()` function?

Breakpoints from segmented function do not change with small set of data, as you see in this example.

I used the same example codes.

Example:

```
set.seed(12)
xx <- 1:100
zz <- runif(100)
yc <- 2+1.5*pmax(xx-35,0)-1.5*pmax(xx-70,0)+15*pmax(zz-.5,0)+
  rnorm(100,0,2)+1.5*pmax(xx-20,0)+15*pmax(zz-.2,0)+
  rnorm(100,0,2)
plot(xx, yc)
# Seeking breakpoints
varbp <- breakpoints(yc ~ xx)
bp <- xx[varbp$breakpoints]
# Using segmented to fit regression line 
modvars <- lm(yc ~ xx)   
seg.var <- segmented(modvars, seg.Z = ~xx, psi = c(25,78))
summary(seg.var) 
#  Estimated Break-Point(s):
#    Est. St.Err
#  psi1.xx 25.694  1.240
#  psi2.xx 72.786  2.086
# Plotando
plot(seg.var, add = T) 
abline(v=25.694, col="green", lwd = 2)
abline(v = 72.786, col="green", lwd = 2)
```

Comment: Although my own experience with `segmented` jibes with your claim that it's not stable. But this example of yours does not support it. I ran it many times with different values of psi, the results are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Since version 0.2-9.0 segmented implements the bootstrap restarting algorithm described in Wood (2001). The bootstrap restarting is expected to escape the local optima of the objective function when the segmented relationship is flat. Notice bootstrap restart runs n.boot iterations regardless of toll that only affects convergence within the inner loop.

Since bootstrap is used by default, it is not surprising (although it surprised me too when I ran into the same problem) that breakpoints detected by `segmented()` are not stable.

The documentation described a way to suppress bootstrapping. This can be done by using the `n.boot` parameter like this:

```
seg.var <- segmented(modvars, seg.Z = ~xx, psi = c(25,78), 
  control = seg.control(n.boot=0))
```

Hope this help. Cheers!